# How to use Enumeration?

Tags: java, enumeration

I was reading Enumerations in Java, and every example I have come across uses the Vector, and then uses `Vector.elements()` to get the Enumeration to iterate using `Enumeration.nextElement()`.

My question is how to use the Enumeration interface with my classes, for example if I create a simple class that implements Enumeration like so:

```
public class Tester implements Enumeration{

    private int [] arr = new int[5];
    private int iterator = 0;
    private int count = 0;

    public boolean insert(int item)
    {
        if (count < 5)
        {
            arr[count-1] = item;
            count++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        if (iterator >= 4)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Object nextElement()
    {
        if (iterator < count)
        {
            iterator++;
            return (Object)arr[iterator -1];
        }
        else
        {
            iterator = 0;
            return nextElement();
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Whats next? I mean how do I use the Enumeration interface with this
   class? What can I do with it (please also explain the purpose of
   Enumeration and implementing it in a class)?
2. How to write the Tester.elements() function similar to
   Vector.elements() which is used in the examples over the internet?
3. What is its equivalent in C#?

Comment: Use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` and `Iterator` instead of `Enumeration`. `Vector` and `Enumeration` are part of the legacy collections, replaced by `ArrayList` and `Iterator` since Java 1.2 (a long time ago).

Comment: The purpose of enumeration is to provide a consistent interface for enumerating over a collection. Elements returns a representation of the collection adhering to the interface. Enumerations are teh olds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enumeration is a Java 1.0 interface that should not be used.  It's been supplanted by java.util.Iterator.  I'd recommend that you prefer that.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that. I have seen the use of enumerations in examples of local classes in Java!

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine `Enumeration` still exists because Sun/Oracle never throws old stuff away in new Java versions, to keep newer versions compatible with older versions. Maybe the examples you were looking at are out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation, it describes the purpose of Enumerations.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html

You may also want to take a look at the Iterator interface, which is kind of a duplicate.